# How to expand the height of a row in listview on clicking it?

Tags: android, listview

I want to increase the height of a row in listview when it is clicked (match parent to be specific) but the height of other rows should not get affected only the clicked one should expand.

This is what I have done after modification of code. Now I want that on click of an item the list should start referring to another XML to show the rows differently

```
public class ExpandableListActivity extends ListActivity 
{

Context context;
int selectedPosition = 0;


String [] mTitles;
String [] mDialogues; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.state_name);
    mDialogues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.capital_name);
    // Use our own list adapter
    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{    

}


private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ListAdapter(Context context)
    {

    }



    public int getCount() {
        return mTitles.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder;
         LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
         if(convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);

                holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } 

         else 
         {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
         }
         holder.text.setText(mTitles[position]);

         return convertView;
    }
}
}
   class ViewHolder { 
    TextView text; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom adapter and in getView (bindView in the case of CursorAdapter) change 
LayoutParams to "match_parent" if position == clickedPosition or to "your default value" otherwise

```
static class ViewHolder { 
    TextView text; 
}

private final LayoutParams MATCH_PARENT = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
private final LayoutParams WRAP_CONTENT = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);

        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }

    holder.text.setText("SomeText"));

    if(position == selectedPosition) {  
        convertView.setLayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT);
    } else {
        convertView.setLayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions , please put some code if possible

Comment: I've added getView of custom adapter. You must pass selectedPosition in it.

Comment: Thanks for the code maxim , can u also tell me some way to use another xml on click of a row in listview to display data in that particular row

Comment: If I understand you properly you should use mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.another_layout, parent, false); in getView with particular layout param. But in this case you have to inflate view every time getView is called (instead of usin convertView). It is possible but will use more memory.

Comment: hi maxim i have added my code please look at it and tell me how to achieve inflating another layout on click of an item

Comment: convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);    Here you should use proper layout (one for clicked item and another for others)